# Azure bot service stopped

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When I created my bot it was working fine and after a couple of days when I’m trying to use this now it says:

> The bot encountered an error or bug. To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.

However I don't have any source code. How to resolve this error?

Comment: Hi Naveen can you confirm if you are using a free trail ACC? and plz attach a screenshot so that we can assist you better.

Comment: Yes it’s free trial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Azure portal locate your app service that is created along with your bot resource and click on the app service that is used and click the restart option and check if it works,
also go through the below question, with the similar issue you are facing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1193326/the-bot-encountered-an-error-or-bug-to-continue-to